# How to send email to multiple users in magento

Tags: php, email, magento

This is my code that is working fine when I'm sending it to one recipient, i.e if I'm using `'rec1@gmail.com'` (single email) it is working fine. However I want to include the second email id as well `rec2@gmail.com` and writing code like this: `'rec1@gmail.com,rec2@gmail.com'` but this is not working.

Let me know how can I implement this functionality ?

```
$templateId = 1;
$sender = array(
    'name' => 'swapnesh',
    'email' => 'sender@gmail.com'
);
$store = Mage::app()->getStore();
$vars = array(
    'my_var' => 15,
    'another_var' => 12
);
$translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');

// Send your email
Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->sendTransactional(
    $templateId,
    $sender,
    'rec1@gmail.com,rec2@gmail.com',
    'Recipient Name',
    $vars,
    $store->getId()
);
$translate->setTranslateInline(true);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is in `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template::send()`

You can see that `$email` and `$names` arguments can be both arrays. So in your case if will be:

```
$recipients = [
    'rec1@gmail.com' => 'Recipient1 Name',
    'rec2@gmail.com' => 'Recipient2 Name'
];

Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->sendTransactional(
    $templateId,
    $sender,
    array_keys($recipients),
    array_values($recipients),
    $vars,
    $store->getId()
);
```

Comment: @Tim.. Wow that working fine..however one concern is that i set this emailfrom backend so it might not going to be exactly 2..how could i solve this problem??

Comment: no worries i sorted it out using $recipients = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT);

Answer (score -2):

For send Email to Multiple recipients in Contact Us Magento, you can tray this way.

Step One, you can Find this line on app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/Controllers/IndexController.php

```
$mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
            /* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
            $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
                ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                ->sendTransactional(
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
                    null,
                    array('data' => $postObject)
                );
```

and modified to bellow :

```
                $recipients = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT);
                if ($recipients)
                {
                        $recipients = explode(";",$recipients);
                        if(count($recipients))
                        {
            foreach($recipients as $recipient) {

            $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
            /* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
            $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
                ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                ->sendTransactional(
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
                    $recipient,
                    null,
                    array('data' => $postObject)
                );

                if (!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
                throw new Exception();
                }
         }
     }
}
```

And don't forget to comment validation javascript on app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/etc/system.xml

Find this line :

```
<recipient_email translate="label">
    <label>Send Emails To</label>
    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
<!--<validate>validate-email</validate>-->
    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</recipient_email>
```

Give comment to this line `<validate>validate-email</validate>`

this code works for me in magento 1.7.0.2 . I hope this help your problem.. :D

Don't forget to save and clear cache..

Comment: Modifying the files outlined in this answer will prevent the application of future security patches.  Core file modifications should **never** occur in production systems.