# Hide product options in email template for customer only not for admin

Tags: magento, email

I want to customize email template for new order mail. I want to hide product options in mail for customers only, but want to show these product options in administrator mail.
I am attaching a scrren-shot.

[image]

Please help me anyone who can get done this task.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't going to provide a full, free answer, you'll still have to work for it after this; but this should point you in the right direction.

[First you have to set up Mage to send e-mail to more than one user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12725307/how-to-send-email-to-multiple-users-in-magento)

Second, you're going to have fun with the transnational e-mails:
     Create another depend (this works like a psuedo if statement) to work on the sender e-mail address
     use the default layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order for admin e-mails
     use a custom call or adjustment to layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order and display quantity and title, but no details.